# Change password page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with this PHP code, it seems logical to me but as I'm new to PHP and MySQL, I am obviously wrong.
I'm trying to set up a change password page for an assignment, and I can't see where I have gone wrong, the code is as follows:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname'];
}
require_once 'PHP/Constants.php';
$conn = new MySQLi(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ('There was a problem connecting to the database');
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($pwdReq = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($pwdReq['Password'] == $_POST['oldPwd']) {
        if ($_POST['confPwd'] == $_POST['newPwd']){
            $change = "INSERT INTO user(Password) VALUES ('newPwd')";
            $pwdChange = mysqli_query($conn, $change);
        } else return "The new passwords do not match!";
    } else return "Please enter a correct password!";
}
```

The body Of my page is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <h2>Change Password</h2>
    <p>
        <label for="oldPwd">Old Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="oldPwd" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="newPwd">New Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="newPwd" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="confPwd">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="confPwd" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

When the page runs all I get is as follows:

> Notice: Undefined index: oldPwd in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Assignment\change_password.php on line 11

Thank you in advance for any help I receive - Nick

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: @SLaks This is a fictional website so I didn't see the need at the moment but it was something I was going to add on after I had done everything, but thank you for the comment

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried that however I still get the same message :-$

Comment: You may not be $_POSTing the oldPwd due to a problem with your form

Comment: Either your form's element isn't named (or typo), or you're missing using a WHERE clause.

Comment: I have included the form above so see if that helps

Comment: You need to do `$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE [[[username_column]]] = $_SESSION['uname']";`  Right now you're selecting all users from the table.

Comment: You need to be particular when querying and use a WHERE clause. You're just selecting everything from your `user` table and not telling it exactly what to look for and in which column.

Comment: Plus, change `VALUES ('newPwd')` to `VALUES ('$newPwd')` you left out the `$` sign which is most likely the issue. Or `('$_POST['newPwd']')` but that's an issue for injection.

Comment: Or assign a variable `$new_pw=$_POST['newPwd'];` then do `VALUES ('$new_pw')` because that's the problem, or one of the contributing factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Always check your POST values before you do anything
- You should select the single record that matches `uname`
- prepare your queries to avoid `SQL` injection

Here's an improved version of your script:

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname'];
}
if(isset($_POST['oldPwd']) && 
   isset($_POST['newPwd']) && 
   isset($_POST['confPwd']){
   //Values are set
    require_once 'PHP/Constants.php';
    $conn = new MySQLi(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
            or die ('There was a problem connecting to the database');
    //Select user from DB where username matches Session
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname = ?";
    //prepare query
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['uname']);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    //get the password from DB
    $pwdReq = $row['Password'];

    if ($pwdReq == $_POST['oldPwd']){   
        if($_POST['confPwd'] == $_POST['newPwd'])) {
            $change = "INSERT INTO user(Password) VALUES (?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $change);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST['newPwd']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            echo "Password has been changed";
        } else{
         echo "The new password does not match confirmation";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Old password not matching the database";
    }
}else{
    echo "oldPwd, confPwd, or confPwd is not set";
}
?>
```

if `oldPwd, confPwd, or confPwd is not set` you will need to figure why. This is not PHP fault anymore. You will need to look in your html and make sure the script is receiving these values

Comment: Thank you very much as I'm new to this it takes me a while to realise things that should be automatic

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to select the fields only for this user, using `WHERE` instead of grabbing all users.  You may need to substitute `WHERE uname =` for your username column.  Also add some protection against SQL injection using mysqli real escape string.  Others have suggested not storing the password in plain text, using bcrypt or a similar function.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname'];
    }
    require_once 'PHP/Constants.php';
    $conn = new MySQLi(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ('There was a problem connecting to the database');
    //Add following line to prevent injection.
    $newPwd = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['newPwd']);
    $oldPwd = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['oldPwd']);
    ////Change here: 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname = $_SESSION['uname']";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($pwdReq = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($pwdReq['Password'] ==  $oldPwd) {
        if ($_POST['confPwd'] == $newPwd){
            $change = "INSERT INTO user(Password) VALUES ('$newPwd')";
            $pwdChange = mysqli_query($conn, $change);
        } else return "The new passwords do not match!";
    } else return "Please enter a correct password!";
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Answers and no explication deserve 10+ upvotes today, just not from me.

Comment: There's an explanation commented in there, and I put an explanation in my comment to the OP :O

Comment: Put it above your code. Grayed out comments are often lost.

Comment: This by the way, is open to SQL injection. Best to inform the OP about it.

Comment: Thank so far for all your help guys however it still doesn't recognise the index oldPwd

Comment: Updated.  Gotta run now!  Thanks, @Fred-ii-

Comment: I have added the suggested edits above and I am still getting the undefined index of oldPwd and newPwd